# Setting a boolean attribute in QWeb template

Tags: odoo, qweb

I am having problems using the QWeb engine and boolean HTML attributes.

I know that in the QWeb rendering engine I can use `t-attf-{attribute name}` in order to set the value of `attribute name` to the format string. The problem is that there is no documented way (or at least I am unable to find it in the documentation) how to set a boolean attribute depending on an expression or a variable from the context.

The problem is that when using [boolean attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#boolean_attributes):

> If a boolean attribute is present, its value is true, and if it's absent, its value is false.

So I cannot use `t-attf-checked` as using `t-attf-checked=""` will put `checked=""` inside the tag. The following will also evaluate to `true` as the simple appearance of the tag in the tag will evaluate to `true`:

- `checked=""`
- `checked="0"`
- `checked="false"`

For example, let's say I have a radio list with multiple inputs and a variable in the context called `elem_num`. Depending on the value of `elem_num` an input of the radio list should have the boolean attribute `checked`.

```
<input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" t-attf-name="radio-1" t-attf-id="radio-1" value="1"/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" t-attf-name="radio-2" t-attf-id="radio-2" value="2"/>
<input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" t-attf-name="radio-3" t-attf-id="radio-3" value="3"/>
```

When `elem_num == 0` the first radio button should be checked, when `elem_num == 1` the second one and when `elem_num == 2` the third one should be.

How can I achieve this without involving any JavaScript code? I am using Odoo 14.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [t-att=mapping](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/javascript/qweb.html#attributes) conditionally to define the `checked` attribute

From QWeb Templates [attributes](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/javascript/qweb.html#attributes) documentation:

> **t-att=mapping**
>    if the parameter is a mapping, each (key, value) pair generates a new attribute and
>    its value

***Example:***

```
t-att="elem_num==1 and {'checked': ''} or {}"
```